# creating hyperlinks from php array elements

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a hashtag system: (Note: $body is a variable that is a post that a user submits.  The hashtags are in the posts.) I have tried to do this using regex but have found this method to be as equally efficient and a bit easier to follow.

```
<?php
$string = $body;
$htag = "#";
$arr = explode(" ", $string);
$arrc = count($arr);
$i = 0;

    while($i < $arrc) {
        if(substr($arr[$i], 0, 1) === $htag) {
            $arr[$i] = "<a href = 'category.php?#=$arr[$i]'>".$arr[$i]."</a>";
        }
            $i++;
    }

$string = implode(" ", $arr);
```

?>

Then, `$string` is echoed later in the page.

My problem with this is that my method for linking the hashtag to the category page using the php array element.  On this page I want to call the word that was "hashtaged" and use a mysql query to get posts that have the hashtags.  However, when I call the `$arr[$i]`, to be echoed, I get an error:

> Undefined offset: 1 on the line in which I call this array element
>   into another variable.

Is there any way I can complete this task in a better and more effective way?

Comment: You should consider `preg_split("\\b", $string)` instead of `explode(" ", $string);`. `\b` knows about word boundaries so the string: `"This is a #tag."` will give you `#tag` instead of `#tag.`.

Comment: Even if you weren't getting an error, I really don't think that `category.php?#=$arr[$i]` is going to do what you want it to.

Comment: Patrick, Would there be a better solution for the hyperlink to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, use `category.php?tag=$arr[$i]` instead (or basically anything except `#` as the parameter key).

Comment: This fixes the issue of the # getting to the other page.  But I am still having a problem with the actual tag getting returned in the title.  Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this can be greatly simplified using some regex and PHP's [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function. @Doge was on the right track, but in my tests, `\b` didn't quite give the results that I think you want.

Basically, you can replace almost all of what you have with

```
$newText = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href='category.php?tag=$1'>#$1</a>", $text);
```

As in…

```
$text = "This is a #hashtag within some #awesometext.";

$newText = preg_replace("/#(\w+)/", "<a href='category.php?tag=$1'>#$1</a>", $text);

echo $newText;
```

The result of this would be…

```
This is a <a href='category.php?tag=hashtag'>#hashtag</a> within some <a href='category.php?tag=awesometext'>#awesometext</a>.
```

[See it in action here](http://3v4l.org/d0gN5)

Comment: If I used this, what could I do to replace the implode function in order to echo the linked hashtag? (As you can probably tell, I am not very familiar with regex.)  :(

Comment: @user3513120 Did you look at the linked example? Simply echo the result of the `preg_replace`. It will output the input text with the tagged words replaced with linked versions of those words.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was trying to combine the original and this method.  However, my major problem was with the page the htags link too.  How would I take the info taken in this script and use it to find all the posts from my db on another page?

Comment: @user3513120 That's really another question entirely. As asked, this particular question is about turning the tagged words in a given text into links. If you find that my answer solves that problem, it should be marked as correct. Before you create a new question about looking up the posts based on the provided tag, I suggest you do some basic searching on topics related to MySQL queries with PHP parameters, as this something for which there are already many answers.